# strange behavior of triangle shape with Firefox done with :before pseudo

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, pseudo-element, shapes

I'm using :before and :after pseudo elements to create shapes. In this case triangular shape that need to be shown as the end of a rectangle. I'm finding myself with this issue which I do not understand why it's happening. The image should look like this image 1, but it looks like image 2.

image 1 (all browsers except FF):

[image]

image 2 (Firefox):

[image]

As asked here you have a jsfiddle with the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/LpXxM/

```
.news-info a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -20px;
  border-right: 20px solid rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.85);
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  content: "";
}
```

I just checked and it seems the issue is simply with the left css property. If instead of left: 20px, it would be left: 22px it works with Firefox, but of course the rest of browsers are then wrong. So, why in the heck firefox has 2px difference with the other browsers? And how to solve this or target this issue?

I'm using normalize as a reset for the site. Can somebody help?!

Comment: Please do not link to your own site. Please use jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @Diodeus I edited my question and inserted a jsfiddle instead of my own site. I hope this helps this answer to be answered.

Comment: @Diodeus Did you have time to check the jsfiddle? I really don't find an answer for this. I would appreciate some help, thanks!